# Why doesnt my while loop works Im trying to write a bash script which loop as long as i didnt take the fouth choice

Tags: bash, if-statement, while-loop

Here is my code 
every time i press 1,2 or 3 so i get out its excute but the out i get done! forever loop 
what do i did wrong ?

```
echo "Wrhat is your name ! :"
read Name
echo  "Hello $Name ! What would you like me to do ?"
echo "Press 1 to create a note !"
echo "Press 2 to write a text and save it in a note?"
echo "Press 3 to copy your new note ?"
echo "Press 4 to exit ?"
echo $Name >> Note.txt 
read Num
while [[ "$Num" != "4" ]] ; do
    if  [[ $Num = "1" ]]; then
        echo > Note.txt
        echo "Done!"
    elif [[ $Num = "2" ]]; then
        echo "Write your text : "
        read text
        echo $text >> Note.txt
        echo "Done!"
    elif [[ $Num = "3" ]]; then
        cp Note.txt Note1.txt
    else
        exit 0
    fi
done
```

Comment: `Num` never changes inside of the loop, so why do you think the loop should stop?

Comment: What should do to let it stop ?

Comment: You don't need `"` inside `[[ ..]]`. Move `read Num` inside `while [[ "$Num" != "4" ]] ; do`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update (read) the $Num variable at the end of the loop on each iteration.

```
echo "Wrhat is your name ! :"
read Name
echo  "Hello $Name ! What would you like me to do ?"
echo "Preas 1 to create a note !"
echo "Preas 2 to write a text and save it in a note?"
echo "Preas 3 to copy your new note ?"
echo "Preas 4 to exit ?"
echo $Name >> Note.txt 
read Num
while [[ "$Num" != "" ]] ; do
    if  [[ $Num = "1" ]]; then
        echo > Note.txt
        echo "Done!"
    elif [[ $Num = "2" ]]; then
        echo "Write your text : "
        read text
        echo $text >> Note.txt
        echo "Done!"
    elif [[ $Num = "3" ]]; then
        cp Note.txt Note1.txt
    else
        exit 0
    fi
    read Num
done
```

Comment: Or better, initialize the variable and then read at the *beginning* of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative with some changes:

- shebang added
- typo in "What is your name" fixed
- "$Name" quoted
- "read Num" in "while" integrated.
- "case" instead of "if ... elif ..."
- Error message on unwanted input

And here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "What is your name ! :"
read Name
echo  "Hello $Name ! What would you like me to do ?"
echo "Press 1 to create a note !"
echo "Press 2 to write a text and save it in a note?"
echo "Press 3 to copy your new note ?"
echo "Press 4 to exit ?"
echo "$Name" >> Note.txt 

while read Num; do
    case "$Num" in

     1) echo > Note.txt
        echo "Done!"
        ;;

     2) echo "Write your text : "
        read text
        echo $text >> Note.txt
        echo "Done!"
        ;;

     3) cp Note.txt Note1.txt
        ;;

     4) break 2
        ;;

     *) echo "Input error"
        ;;
    esac
done
```